# How to append all urls in a string with query builder url parameters?

Tags: php, query-string

I am trying to replace all existing URLs in a body string to append the Google Analytics query paramaters. It works on URLs with no parameters, but with URLs which already have some parameters, all parameters are lost.

```
    <?php
$add = array(
 'utm_source'=>'edm',
 'utm_medium'=>'email',
 'utm_campaign'=>'product_notify');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('First Link <a href="http://www.google.com">no param</a><br />
                Second Link <a href="http://www.google.com/">no param with /</a><br />
                Third Link <a href="http://www.google.com?query=one">one  param</a><br />
                Fourth Link <a href="http://www.google.com?query=one&q2=two">two  param</a><br />');

foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link){
    $url = parse_url($link->getAttribute('href'));
    $gets = isset($url['query']) ? array_merge(parse_str($url['query'])) : $add;
    $newstring = '';
    if(isset($url['scheme'])) $newstring .= $url['scheme'].'://';
    if(isset($url['host']))   $newstring .= $url['host'];
    if(isset($url['port']))   $newstring .= ':'.$url['port'];
    if(isset($url['path']))   $newstring .= $url['path'];
    $newstring .= '?'.http_build_query($gets);
    if(isset($url['fragment']))   $newstring .= '#'.$url['fragment'];
    $link->setAttribute('href',$newstring);
 }
 $html = $doc->saveHTML();
 echo $html;
 ?>
```

OUTPUT
First Link no param:

```
http://www.google.com/?utm_source=edm&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=product_notify
```

Third Link one param: http://www.google.com/?

As you can see, the first Link works fine. But the third links looses it original parameters.

Please review and suggest what mistake am I doing, and how to keep existing parameters in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see on the manual page here http://php.net/parse_str the parse_str function doesn't return the array of values, it writes it to the second parameter and returns void always. You would have called array_merge on a single array anyway. So you can take your existing line:

```
$gets = isset($url['query']) ? array_merge(parse_str($url['query'])) : $add;
```

and replace it with something like:

```
$params = array();
if (isset($url['query'])) {
    parse_str($url['query'], $params);
}
$gets = array_merge($params, $add);
```

In the end you will get something like this: http://codepad.org/5VIEcAWy